# Read body from raw email

Tags: python, imaplib

> How can i read the body of any mail its not coming properly in this
>   manner

I tried this :

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')


mail.login(email_user, email_pass)

mail.select('Inbox')

type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
mail_ids = data[0]
id_list = mail_ids.split()

for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)' )
    raw_email = data[0][1] # converts byte literal to string removing b''
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
    subject = str(email_message).split("Subject: ", 1)[1].split("\nTo:", 1)[0]
    #body = str(email_message).split("body: ", 1)[1].split("\nTo:", 1)[0]
    print(email_message);
```

its showing [image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you are exactly asking but if you want to get the body, you might want to use `get_body()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html for documentation.

Comment: @Swarnadeep. Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to parse the email and access the body, then consider using  [mail-parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mail-parser). It's a simple mail-parser that takes as input a raw email and generates a parsed object.

```
import mailparser

mail = mailparser.parse_from_file(f)
mail = mailparser.parse_from_file_obj(fp)
mail = mailparser.parse_from_string(raw_mail)
mail = mailparser.parse_from_bytes(byte_mail)
```

How to Use:

```
mail.body #use this to access the body contents
mail.to
```

Comment: comment from my side, as I came to this post - if anyone has the same problem, installing mailparser is pip install mail-parser (with a minus in between :D )